# Error when collecting IntStream to map

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8, java-stream, javac

The following code

```
String[] values = ...
.... 
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    map.put("X" + i, values[i]);
}
```

is converted by IntelliJ to:

```
Map<String, Object> map = IntStream.range(0, values.length)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                i -> "X" + i,
                i -> values[i],
                (a, b) -> b));
```

which can be shortened to

```
Map<String, Object> map = IntStream.range(0, values.length)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    i -> "X" + i,
                    i -> values[i]));
```

The 2 stream versions don't compile.

IntelliJ, hints that there is an issue with the i in values[i]:

> Incompatible types.
>         Required: int
>         Found:    java.lang.Object

The compiler complains:

> Error:(35, 17) java: method collect in interface java.util.stream.IntStream cannot be applied to given types;
>     required: java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.ObjIntConsumer,java.util.function.BiConsumer
>     found: java.util.stream.Collector>
>     reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) R
>       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: what is `values`, could you include its declaration as well. Also onto IntelliJ's suggestion, seems inconsistent. Just put a print `map` statement between the declaration and loop. It won't suggest you to *replace with collect* anymore.

Comment: String[] values = ...

Comment: I imagine `Collector`s don't support primitives, and that could be why the lambdas are converted to `Object`, because `boxed()` fixes it.

Comment: You should totally file a bug with them anyways

Comment: Filed: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-180417

Answer (score 10):

Not very certain about how intelliJ's suggestion would work there, it seems inconsistent. Just put a

```
System.out.print(map);
```

statement between the declaration and loop and then it won't suggest you *Replace with collect* any further.

---

While using the `IntStream#collect`, the compilation fails for the reason that implementation of [`collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.ObjIntConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) method expects three specified arguments as visible in the error as well while the

```
Collectors.toMap(i -> "X" + i, i -> values[i])
```

would result in only a single argument of type `Collector`.

---

Better way to convert the expression would be though to

- either use `forEach`

  ```
  Map<String, Object> map;
  IntStream.range(0, values.length).forEach(i -> map.put("X" + i, values[i]));
  ```
- Or use [`boxed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#boxed--) to convert the `IntStream` to `Stream<Integer>` as:-

  ```
  Map<String, Object> map = IntStream.range(0, values.length).boxed()
             .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> "X" + i, i -> values[i], (a, b) -> b));
  ```
- Or as suggested by @Holger, you can avoid using forEach and boxing overhead and modify the construct to make use of the `IntStream.collect` three-arg variant as:-

  ```
  Map<String, Object> map = IntStream.range(0, values.length)
             .collect(HashMap::new, (m,i) -> m.put("X"+i,values[i]), Map::putAll);
  ```

Comment: I would use the first one. The second one, with that `boxed` will lead to too many boxes and unboxes between `Integer` and int.

Comment: While your solutions are valid, they don't answer my question: why doesn't it compile?

Comment: @msayag Edited. Was considering the log as self-explanatory though. Using boxed on the other hand converts the `IntStream` to `Stream` and the `collect` is overloaded in that class to accept your `Collector` passed.

Comment: Use the three-arg variant: `Map<String, Object> map = IntStream.range(0, values.length) .collect(HashMap::new, (m,i) -> m.put("X"+i,values[i]), Map::putAll);` avoids the boxing overhead without the `forEach` code smell.

Comment: @Holger Thanks for the insight. Updated. Suggested formerly based on the IntelliJ's suggestions :)